# Why is env context not available in Github action job level if statement?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to trigger a reusable workflow conditionally using an environment variable in an if statement. The caller workflow yaml looks like

```
…
env:
  build_enabled: ${{ github.event.inputs.build_enabled || 'yes' }}
 
jobs:
  build_production:
    if: ${{ env.build_enabled == 'yes' || contains(github.ref, 'main') }}
    uses: <username>/<repo_name>/.github/workflows/<workflow_name>.yml@<branch_name>
    with:
      environment: production
```

Github displays the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. github/workflows/<workflow_name>.yml (Line: 30, Col: 9): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.build_enabled == 'yes'
```

Why the error? Why is the env context not available in the if statement? How can I use an environment variable in the if statement?

Comment: Also, see the [limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of reusable workflows.

Comment: I see there is stuff mentioned about env propagation etc, but in this case my workflow hasn’t even been triggered yet so none of that is relevant. The env is not available in the caller workflow. Surely that’s not normal?

Comment: Well, you may [create an issue](https://github.com/github/docs/issues/new/choose) on their docs repo to further discuss this design decision. In conjunction with limitations above, you might want to take a look at the [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability). You can observe that `env` is not available against `jobs.<job_id>.if` in that list.

Comment: For your specific use case, looks like you can simply remove `env` and directly use `github` context in `if` and that should work.

Comment: But the variable I want to use for the if condition is in env. How would I use Github context to accomplish same task? Ie if X trigger reusable workflow

Comment: In your above example, `build_enabled` is being set using `github` context. You can directly use it with `if` for the similar effect.

Comment: Really? I thought build_enabled was set as an env variable. Where is it available in the github context?

Comment: You can use `github.event.inputs.build_enabled` or `inputs.build_enabled` directly in the `if` condition of the job. You won't need to set it as an env var and the workflow will become valid.

Comment: I see what you mean now, use it directly from the input. The issue with that is that my workflows are run manually, where I think that will work, but also directly on push, where I set defaults. That’s why I use env variables. I was hoping to be able to have working if statements in both cases. But actually I suppose I could just use the default in the if without setting an env var. so perhaps that would work.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or, you may simply enable/disable based on the `github.event_name` i.e. use `inputs` if its `workflow_dispatch` event, do something else for other events e.g. `push`, `pull_request`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation reads

> *You can access this context from any **`step`** in a job. This object contains the properties listed below.*
>
> ~ [`env` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context)

So, you should not use the context in `if` expressions of a **`job`**.

To address the challenge, directly use the `gitHub` context as it is available in all scopes of expression.

```
…
env:
  build_enabled: ${{ github.event.inputs.build_enabled || 'yes' }}
 
jobs:
  build_production:
    if: ${{ (github.event.inputs.build_enabled || 'yes') == 'yes' || contains(github.ref, 'main') }}
    uses: <username>/<repo_name>/.github/workflows/<workflow_name>.yml@<branch_name>
    with:
      environment: production
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don’t follow your reasoning though. Docs also say “You can use the env context in the value of any key in a step except for the id and uses keys”. That suggests env is accessible in if statements, doesn’t it?

Comment: You may use it in the `if` expression associated with a `step`, but **not** that of a `job`.

Comment: So there is no way to do if X trigger reusable workflow?

Comment: @vy218 don't forget to remove your down vote to be fair, as you have gained explanation of the concept and actual solution as well :-)